# Retirar valores para ficheiro SQL não esta a funcionar

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Eu tenho este código, que pega Strings e as mete numa dataBase, mas o problema é que ele esta a criar a dataBase mas não sei porque , não esta a inserir os valores na mesma. Em baixo deixo os ficheiros de xml e java da activity que estou a tentar retirar os valores, e deixo também o documento java do SQLiteOpenHelper . Agradeço desde ja a ajuda.

Tab1Testes.java :

```
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1tests, container, false);

    add_test = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_test);
    date_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_button);
    hora_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_text);
    hora_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_button);
    date_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    sala_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sala_text);
    myDB = new DataBaseHelper(getContext());


            date_button.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            DatePickerDialog date_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                                    getActivity(),
                                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                                    dateSetListener,
                                    year, month, day);
                            date_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                            date_dialog.show();


                        }

                        ;
                    }

            );

    dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            date_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            date_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            date_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dt = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            try {
                sdf.parse(dt);
                date_text.setText(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };




    hora_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hora_button);

    hora_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, hourSetListener, hora, minutos, true);
                    mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
            }
    );

    hourSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hora, int minutos) {
            hora_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            hora_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hora2 = (hora + ":" + minutos);
            hora_text.setText(hora2);
        }
    };

    hora_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,hourSetListener,hora,minutos,true);
            mTimePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            mTimePicker.show();
        }

    });

    date_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog date_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    getActivity(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    dateSetListener,
                    year, month, day);
            date_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            date_dialog.show();
        }
    });

    addData();
    return rootView;
}



public void addData(){
    add_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData("Portugues", sala_text.getText().toString(), dt, hora2);
                if (isInserted==true){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Teste inserido ao calendario",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    date_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hora_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    date_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sala_text.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Preencha todos os espaços",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Tab1testes.xml :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_test"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
    android:text="Adicionar o teste"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disciplina"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
    android:text="Disciplina:"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sala"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/disciplina"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
    android:text="Sala:"
    android:textSize="35sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Dia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sala"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
    android:text="Dia:"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Dia"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
    android:text="Hora:"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ESCOLHER DATA"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Dia"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Dia"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Dia" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hora_button"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Dia"
    android:text="ESCOLHER DATA"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="setDate"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hora_text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ESCOLHER HORA"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Hora"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hora_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ESCOLHER HORA"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Hora"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sala" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sala_text"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sala"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Hora"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nª/Nome da sala"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/disciplina"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/disciplina"
    android:scrollbarSize="25sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/disciplina" />
```

DataBaseHelper:

```
    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Exames.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Exames_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "DISCIPLINA";
public static final String COL_3 = "SALA";
public static final String COL_4 = "DIA";
public static final String COL_5 = "HORA";




public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , DISCIPLINA TEXT , SALA TEXT,DIA TEXT)" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}

public boolean insertData(String disciplina,String sala,String dia,String hora){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_2,disciplina);
    values.put(COL_3,sala);
    values.put(COL_4,dia);
    values.put(COL_5,hora);
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        if(result==-1){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean insertData(String disciplina,String sala,String dia,String hora){
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COL_2,disciplina);
            values.put(COL_3,sala);
            values.put(COL_4,dia);
            values.put(COL_5,hora);
            long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
                if(result==-1){
                    return false;
                }else {
                    return true;
                }

    }
```

Esse trecho `long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values)` somente irá retornar o valor -1 caso ocorra algum erro no sqLite ele não valida valores iguais. Terás que criar uma função para testar se o registro com o mesmo ID já foi inserido antes!